# My own NAS with a SR20969-06A hot-swap Bay. How to turn off the alarm

Tags: network-attached-storage, hotswap

So I wanted to build my own NAS with a ATI3IONT-I-Deluxe Mobo I have still lying around.
I bought this 4-bay hotswap unit, that's meant to go in a server casing (iex the SR209) which has two power connector's (the one you'd use with older IDE 3,5" disks) and 4 SATA-ports.

When I boot up the OS (arch linux), I can see the disks with `parted -l`, so it seems to work fine.
The problem is that the hot-swap bay is sounding the alarm (possibly it's default behavior after a power interruption).

In the back there are two pins with the underscript 'mute_alm'.
Shorting these, does not stop the alarm.

So either, this is not how you'd mute the alarm, or something else is up which turns the alarm on immediately after.

Can anyone suggest me what to explore or what I might be doing wrong ?
(I probably should have askes if there was anyone with experience with this SR20969 bay or something similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, I found it
(but not before this question gained me a -1 reputation :( )

Anyway, underneath the fan was a little schematics, explaining that there was a certain connector that had certain pins of which two were labeled respectively alarm+ and alarm.
Shorting these stopped the alarm.
So I connected a momentary switch to these pins and now I all set !

Hopefully this very short quest will be of use to someone...